# Octave advanced textread usage, bash

Tags: linux, bash, octave

I have following text file:

> 079082084072079032084069067072000000000,0
>   082078032049050032067072065082071069000,1
>   076065066032065083083084000000000000000,0
>   082078032049050072082000000000000000000,1
>   082078032049050072082000000000000000000,1
>   082078032049050072082000000000000000000,1
>   070083087032073073032080068000000000000,0
>   080067065032049050032072082000000000000,0
>   082078032056072082000000000000000000000,1
>   070083087032073073073000000000000000000,0
>   082078032087069069075069078068000000000,1
>   082078032049050072082000000000000000000,1
>   077065073078084032077069067072032073073,0
>   082078032049050072082000000000000000000,1
>   080067065032049050032072082000000000000,0
>   082078032049050072082000000000000000000,1

I need too matrices:
X size 16x13
Y size 16x1

I want to separate each row of the file into 13 values, example:
079 082 084 072 079 032 084 069 067 072 000 000 000

Is it possible to import it into octave using **textread** function?

If no, can it be done using Linux bash command?

Comment: What are you doing with the last field after the comma? Throwing it away?

Comment: The last field goes to matrix Y 16x1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with `textscan` (see bottom if you really want to use `textread`:

```
octave> txt = "079082084072079032084069067072000000000,0\n082078032049050032067072065082071069000,1";
octave> textscan (txt, repmat ("%3d", 1, 13))
ans = 
{
  [1,1] =

    79
    82

  [1,2] =

    82
    78

  [1,3] =

    84
    32

  [1,4] =

    72
    49
[...]
```

Note that you are reading them as numeric values, so you do not get the preceding zeros. If you want them, you can either read them as string by using "%3s" in the format (extra trouble to handle and reduced performance since you will then be handling cell arrays).

Since you are reading from a file:

```
[fid, msg] = fopen ("data.txt", "r");
if (fid)
  error ("failed to fopen 'data.txt': %s", msg);
endif 
data = textscan (fid, repmat ("%3d", 1, 13));
fclose (fid);
```

If you really want to use `textread`:

```
octave> [d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9, d10, d11, d12, d13] = textread ("data.txt", repmat ("%3d", 1, 13))
d1 =

  79
  82
  76
[...]    
d2 =

  82
  78
  65
[...]
```

or:

```
octave> data = cell (1, 13);
octave> [data{:}] = textread ("data.txt", repmat ("%3d", 1, 13))
data = 
{
  [1,1] =

    79
    82
    76
[...]

  [1,2] =

    82
    78
    65
[...]
```

If you need to capture the value after the comma (not really part of your original question), you can use:

```
octave> textscan (txt, [repmat("%3d", 1, 13) ",%1d"])
ans = 
{
  [1,1] =

    79
    82

  [1,2] =

    82
    78

  [1,3] =

    84
    32

[...]

  [1,14] =

0
1
```

}

Comment: And how I suppose to put value after comma into numeric matrix Y 16X1?

Comment: @AlexDvoretskiy I have edited the question to mention how to handle the value after the comma (which on my understanding, was not part of the original question)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily by reading three characters at a time using `read` in the shell:

```
while IFS="${IFS}," read -rn3 val tail; do
    [[ $tail ]] && echo || printf '%s ' "$val"
done < file
```

This implementation assumes that if we encounter a value *after* the comma, we should go to the next line.